# Why is this JOIN inefficent?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, join

I am trying to get data from multiple tables at once.  In my old system I would make a query, get the data I needed, and then use it for the next query.  I wanted to avoid making multiple queries so I combined them with joins:

```
 SELECT `to`.`id` , `to`.`group`, `to`.`email`, `pTo`.`min_offer`, COUNT(`offerRes`.`id`), `settingsRes`.`email`
                                FROM `members` AS `to`

                                LEFT JOIN (
                                  SELECT `id` , `min_offer`
                                  FROM `profile`
                                ) pTo ON pTo.id = to.id

                                LEFT JOIN (
                                  SELECT `id`, `from`,`to`
                                  FROM `offers`
                                ) offerRes ON offerRes.from = ? && offerRes.to = to.id

                                LEFT JOIN (
                                  SELECT `id`, `email`
                                  FROM `user_settings`
                                )  settingsRes ON settingsRes.id = to.id

                                WHERE to.id = ? LIMIT 1
```

I use the ID that is passed in (to.id) to obtain results from the profiles table and the offers table and the user settings table.  These tables all have a PRIMARY id to which everything is mapped to.  My PHP users prepared statements however I replaced the ? with hard values in PHPMyAdmin.  My EXPLAIN is as follows:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY         to     const    PRIMARY       PRIMARY   4         const     1   
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL        45  
1   PRIMARY     <derived3>  ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL        1   
1   PRIMARY     <derived4>  ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL        15  
4   DERIVED     user_settingsALL    NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL        15  
3   DERIVED     offers      system  NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL        1   
2   DERIVED     profile     ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL        45
```

Why is MySQL going through all 45 rows in the profile field when it can do a simple lookup as my query is based on the PRIMARY key `id`?  Any way to make this more efficent?  All I want is a table of the following:

```
id (from members) - this is optional as this is what is obtained from the user and passed in to SELECT against
group (from members) - corresponding to the id that is passed in
email (from members) - corresponding to the id that is passed in
min_offer (from profile) - also corresponding to the id that is passed in
NUM_ROWS(from offers) - number of rows corresponding to the id taht is passed in and another number that is also passed in.  The offers table has a PRIMARY id but it is a different ID than what is passed in.
email (from user_settings) - corresponding to the id that is passed in
```

Comment: The more non-INNER joins, the less efficient the query.

Comment: As far as I understand with inner join if any of those sub queries returns no rows the entire thing returns NULL.  This is undesirable.  I still don't see why it has to search through all 45 records when it's doing a LEFT JOIN ON idCol = someOtherIdCol.  IDs are primary key.  It shouldn't have to search through 45 rows unless I am reading EXPLAIN wrong?

Comment: The left join should review the 45 rows. All rows of the table members will be in the result, you can not find the row corresponding to another table will have null fields

Comment: @Ignacio - the efficiency in this case has nothing to do with the type of joins, it is the use of derived tables where the table can be accessed directly!

Comment: So you're telling me it's faster to just execute multiple queries?  SE:ECT `f1`,`f2` FROM `memnbers` WHERE `id` = ? LIMIT 1 ... SELECT `f1` FROM `profile` WHERE `id` = ? LIMIT 1.  At least this will take advantage of the primary keys and do fast lookups.  Any way to combine them for code prettyness ane efficency (less mysql calls = better I assume)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is MySQL going through all 45 rows in the profile field when it can do a simple lookup as my query is based on the PRIMARY key id?

Because you're joining to the *results* of sub-queries, which will include every record from the table:

```
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT `id` , `min_offer`
  FROM `profile`
) pTo ON pTo.id = to.id

-- etc.
```

Instead, join to the tables directly:

```
LEFT JOIN `profile` AS pTo ON pTo.id = to.id

LEFT JOIN `offers` AS offerRes ON offerRes.from = ? && offerRes.to = to.id

LEFT JOIN `user_settings` AS settingsRes ON settingsRes.id = to.id
```

Comment: Perfect.  Very efficient and runs like it's supposed to.  I was unaware of how to use JOIN.  I assumed you needed to specify which fields you want in your JOINed query so you can have "access" to those variables later (i.e. now I can use `pTo`.min_offer in another query).  Now that I see you can do it like this why in the world would anyone use subqueries like I did before?  This combines a lot of queries into 1 and still maintains efficiency.